# Resharper Surroundwith для списка строк

Tags: c++, resharper

Как использовать Resharper SurroundWith Для списка строк ?
Есть строки,
foo
bar
foo1
Я хочу выделить их все и применить макрос( добавляющий struct {} )
Ожидаемый результат:
struct foo
{
foo(int a);
}
struct bar
{
foo(int a);
}
struct foo1
{
foo(int a);
}

Какой должен быть примерный синтакс ?

Comment: Можно сделать surround with live templates и там такой же синтаксис, собственно, как в live templates. Откройте и посмотрите примеры уже существующих, там ещё ссылка должна быть на синтаксис

Comment: @dIm0n Да но примеров , с применением для списка там нету ? 
Нужно вот так
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/434016090000064513/739217956147298424/unknown.png
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/434016090000064513/739218053618860153/unknown.png

Comment: Разбить `$SELECTION$` на отдельные слова нельзя, по-моему. `regularExpression(...)` для него не применяется, например. Самое близкое дал в ответе

Comment: @dIm0n  спасиб, но я и так сам умею. Хотелось чего то более универсального

Comment: А решение с текстовой заменой не подойдёт ctrl+r? Надо именно делать в выделении это?

Comment: @dIm0n Ну представь у тебя 40 классов, ты их все будешь выделять очень долго и муторно ! Я думал найти какое то универсальное решение на будущее, но думаю проще через обычный SQL Синтаксис сгенерировать , и ничего ставить не надо( типа питона )

Answer (score 0):

Сделал с помощью такого *live template*:

```
struct $SELECTION$ {
    $SELECTION$(int a);
};
```

Демонстрация:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]